# What is the fasted way to insert a pandas data frame into a database with the same columns?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Suppose i i have a dataframe df and it has the same columns as a sql table.
What is the simplest (and most efficient way) to insert the dataframe into a table.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']})
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')
conn = engine.connect()

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
session = Session(bind=engine)

# No assume that the database has a table Users with one column "name" 
# is there a function, which adds all entries of the dataframe to the sql table?
# This should also works with dates/floats type of columns and multiple columns
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way?
Just use

```
df.to_sql('tableName', databaseConnectionObject, if_exists='append')
```

I think it is efficient as well, but can't say whether it is the most efficient or not, you need to test out the things

Comment: this is a dream :)